# how to pass multiple arguments/parameters while executing pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to pass multiple arguments while executing the python script as a condition.
Below is my code but i have to perform same steps with multiple condition.
there are 4 different files for client 1 and 2 with data and metadata errors.
so, If I pass `python.py client1,data,date`
then my function should pick the first file name client1_data_error_file_1 and create a dataframe and insert in the database.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from operator import itemgetter
    import glob
    import bz2
    import csv
    import import argparse
    
    
    client1_data_error_file_1=10_client1_AAAAAA_data_error_date.bz2
    client1_metadata_error_file_1=10_client1_AAAAAA_metadata_error_date.bz2
    client2_data_error_file_1=20_client2_AAAAAA_data_error_date.bz2
    client2_metadata_error_file_1=10_client1_AAAAAA_metadata_error_date.bz2
    
    def load_errors_database(argument,client,error):
    header = ["filedate", "errorcode", "errorROEID", "ROEID", "type", "rawrecord", "filename"]
    data = []
    req_cols = itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10)
    
    for error_filename in glob.glob("*.bz2"):
        with bz2.open(error_filename, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f_error_file:
            csv_input = csv.reader(f_error_file, skipinitialspace=True)
            
            for orig_row in csv_input:
                row = req_cols(orig_row)
                data.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], ",".join(orig_row), error_filename])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# Insert Dataframe into SQL Server:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.error_table (filedate, errorcode, errorROEID, ROEID, type, rawrecord, filename) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", row.filedate, row.errorcode, row.errorROEID, row.ROEID, row.type, row.rawrecord, row.filename)
cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

How do I pass these arugments as a condition? not necessarily it has to be function.
When I execute my python code from terminal, I would like to pass

```
python_error_file.py client1, data,date
```

Now it should pick the first file and do the necessary steps. If I pass

```
python_error_file.py client2, metadata,date
```

It should pick the 4th file and do the required steps.
Steps are same for all four files. I just have to pass these as parameter while executing the code.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I think you should fix the indentation error first.

Comment: If you type `python_error_file.py client1 metadata data`, and you `import sys` then the `sys.argv` array will contain `['python_error_file.py', 'client1', 'metadata', 'data']`.  Note that you don't use commas on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argparse` is your friend for creating hand command-line tools with simple syntax. Here is a snippet to help you:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='client file parser')
parser.add_argument(
    '-c', '--client',
    help='client name',
    type=str
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-m', '--metadata',
    help='meta data',
    type=str,
    default=''
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-d', '--data',
    help='data',
    type=str,
    default=''
)

args = parser.parse_args()

load_errors_database(args.client, args.metadata, args.data)
```

Usage:

```
python file.py -c client1 -m metadata -d data
```

Comment: This is the snippet after writing the steps I want to insert into database ? I still have to read the file through function right ?and parameters to function will be client ,error and date ?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't follow what the  ``load_errors_database`` is doing, so I left it out. You can pass the ``args`` parameters from user input into your function.